# Call ShowWindowCommand() from MainWindow.xaml.cs

Tags: c#

I want to call the function ShowWindowCommand() and HideWindowCommand() from my MainWindow().

I have the following class:

```
public class NotifyIconViewModel
{
    public ICommand ShowWindowCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegateCommand
            {
                CanExecuteFunc = () => Application.Current.MainWindow == null,
                CommandAction = () =>
                {
                    Application.Current.MainWindow = new WorkingTimer.MainWindow();
                    Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public ICommand HideWindowCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegateCommand
            {
                CommandAction = () => Application.Current.MainWindow.Close(),
                CanExecuteFunc = () => Application.Current.MainWindow != null
            };
        }
    }
```

Normally, ShowWindowCommand() and HideWindowsCommand() are called from Context Menu in NotifyIconRessource.xaml

```
<ContextMenu x:Shared="false" x:Key="SysTrayMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Show Window" Command="{Binding ShowWindowCommand}"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Hide Window" Command="{Binding HideWindowCommand}"/>
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Header="Reset Timer" Command="{Binding ResetTimerCommand}"/>
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Header="Exit" Command="{Binding ExitApplicationCommand}" />
    </ContextMenu>
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: You will have to set the NotifyIconViewModel's instance as the data context for your view.

Comment: I have tried:`public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            NotifyIconViewModel ShowWindowCommand = new NotifyIconViewModel();
            ShowWindowCommand = obj => true;` But I don't know how to call the function itself :(

Comment: Also this is not working: `NotifyIconViewModel ShowWindowCommand = new NotifyIconViewModel();
            ShowWindowCommand.ShowWindowCommand();`

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You will first have to create a public property of the class and then set it as the data context of the view:

```
public NotifyIconViewModel NotifyIconVM { get; set; }

MainWindow() 
{ 
    InitializeComponent();
    NotifyIconVM = new NotifyIconViewModel();
    DataContext = NotifyIconVM;
}
```

Setting the data context will tell the view where to look for the command.

Comment: Thank you for your support at first! But how can I call the HideWindowCommand(); in addition do I need to set the DataContext in the MainWindow.xaml ?

Comment: You have already bound the HideWindowCommand inside the menu item in the xaml. You need to set the data context in the MainWindow.xaml.cs and it should automatically call the command after you click the menu item on the UI.

Comment: Maybe there is an understand issue. The menu with Hide and Show is working fine already. The idea is to start the application and 1 second later the HideWindowCommand() function should be called to minimize the app into the taskbar.

Comment: Any idea ? Can someone help me ?